# Как сделать замену текста на ссылку с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: url, регулярные-выражения, ссылки, javascript

Есть текстовая строка вида

```
var text = "somthing text and habrahabr.ru/login.php?vk=1 link "
```

Ссылка взята от балды. Нужно любым способом сделать замену этой строки на ссылку. И не только такого вида.

Что еще надо учесть:

- поддержка этих протоколов(т.е.
     преобразование в ссылку): http://,
     https://, ftp://, skype://, steam://
- любые доменные имена (как, например,
     .рф) и поддержка поддоменов
     собственно
- поддержка кириллицы в имени домена

Все это завернуть в функцию, к примеру. Уже написано и частично работает:

```
function findAndReplaceLink(inputText) {
    var url = "http://test.com"
    var pattern = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)?)/gi;
    var replacedText = inputText.replace(pattern, '<a href="'+url+'/go.php?to=$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
    return replacedText;
}
```

На выходе должна быть строка:

```
"somthing text and <a href='http://test.com/go.php?to=http://habrahabr.ru/login.php?vk=1' target='_blank'>habrahabr.ru/login.php?vk=1</a> link "
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, добить функционал. Заранее благодарен.

---

**UPDATE.** нашел код с подобным функционалом (взял с vk.com), но не знаю, как изменить под свои нужды, под мою функцию. не поможете?

```
message = (message || '').replace(/(^|[^A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_])(https?:\/\/)?((?:[A-Za-z\$0-9А-Яа-яёЁ](?:[A-Za-z\$0-9\-\_А-Яа-яёЁ]*[A-Za-z\$0-9А-Яа-яёЁ])?\.){1,5}[A-Za-z\$рфуконлайнстРФУКОНЛАЙНСТ\-\d]{2,22}(?::\d{2,5})?)((?:\/(?:(?:\&amp;|\&#33;|,[_%]|[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.~=;:]+|\[[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\]|\([A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\))*(?:,[_%]|[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.~=;:]*[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\_#%?+\/\$~=]|\[[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\]|\([A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яёЁ\-\_#%?+\/\$.,~=;:]*\)))?)?)/ig, 
      function () { // copied to notifier.js:3401
        var matches = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments),
            prefix = matches[1] || '',
            protocol = matches[2] || 'http://',
            domain = matches[3] || '',
            url = domain + (matches[4] || ''),
            full = (matches[2] || '') + matches[3] + matches[4];

        if (domain.indexOf('.') == -1 || domain.indexOf('..') != -1) return matches[0];
        var topDomain = domain.split('.').pop();
        if (topDomain.length > 6 || indexOf('info,name,aero,arpa,coop,museum,mobi,travel,xxx,asia,biz,com,net,org,gov,mil,edu,int,tel,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ai,al,am,an,ao,aq,ar,as,at,au,aw,ax,az,ba,bb,bd,be,bf,bg,bh,bi,bj,bm,bn,bo,br,bs,bt,bv,bw,by,bz,ca,cc,cd,cf,cg,ch,ci,ck,cl,cm,cn,co,cr,cu,cv,cx,cy,cz,de,dj,dk,dm,do,dz,ec,ee,eg,eh,er,es,et,eu,fi,fj,fk,fm,fo,fr,ga,gd,ge,gf,gg,gh,gi,gl,gm,gn,gp,gq,gr,gs,gt,gu,gw,gy,hk,hm,hn,hr,ht,hu,id,ie,il,im,in,io,iq,ir,is,it,je,jm,jo,jp,ke,kg,kh,ki,km,kn,kp,kr,kw,ky,kz,la,lb,lc,li,lk,lr,ls,lt,lu,lv,ly,ma,mc,md,me,mg,mh,mk,ml,mm,mn,mo,mp,mq,mr,ms,mt,mu,mv,mw,mx,my,mz,na,nc,ne,nf,ng,ni,nl,no,np,nr,nu,nz,om,pa,pe,pf,pg,ph,pk,pl,pm,pn,pr,ps,pt,pw,py,qa,re,ro,ru,rs,rw,sa,sb,sc,sd,se,sg,sh,si,sj,sk,sl,sm,sn,so,sr,ss,st,su,sv,sx,sy,sz,tc,td,tf,tg,th,tj,tk,tl,tm,tn,to,tp,tr,tt,tv,tw,tz,ua,ug,uk,um,us,uy,uz,va,vc,ve,vg,vi,vn,vu,wf,ws,ye,yt,yu,za,zm,zw,рф,укр,сайт,онлайн,срб,cat,pro,local'.split(','), topDomain) == -1) {
          if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(topDomain) || !matches[2]) {
            return matches[0];
          }
        }

        if (matches[0].indexOf('@') != -1) {
          return matches[0];
        }
        try {
          full = decodeURIComponent(full);
        } catch (e){}

        if (full.length > 55) {
          full = full.substr(0, 53) + '..';
        }
        full = clean(full).replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

        if (!susp && domain.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+\.)?(vkontakte\.ru|vk\.com|vkadre\.ru|vshtate\.ru|userapi\.com|vk\.me)$/)) {
          url = replaceEntities(url).replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9#%;_\-.\/?&=\[\]])/g, encodeURIComponent);
          var tryUrl = url, hashPos = url.indexOf('#/'), mtch, oncl = '';
          if (hashPos >= 0) {
            tryUrl = url.substr(hashPos + 1);
          } else {
            hashPos = url.indexOf('#!');
            if (hashPos >= 0) {
              tryUrl = '/' + url.substr(hashPos + 2).replace(/^\//, '');
            }
          }
          mtch = tryUrl.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:vk\.com|vkontakte\.ru)?\/([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+)\??$/);
          if (mtch) {
            if (mtch[1].length < 32) {
              oncl = ' mention_id="' + mtch[1] + '" onclick="return mentionClick(this, event)" onmouseover="mentionOver(this)"';
            }
          }
          return prefix + '<a href="'+ (protocol + url).replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + '" target="_blank"' + oncl + '>' + full + '</a>';
        }
        return prefix + '<a href="away.php?utf=1&to=' + encodeURIComponent(protocol + replaceEntities(url)) + '" target="_blank" onclick="return goAway(\''+ clean(protocol + url) + '\', {}, event);">' + full + '</a>';
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки разобрался. Вот код рабочей функции:

http://pastebin.com/qSmfKRC2